# What is FX symbol on the ssis execute sql task ssis 2012?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

This is not there in SSIS 2008. What is this FX symbol on the execute sql task?
It seems this is considered a parameter. Is there any good article on this?

Can anybody tell what is the use of this:

[image]

Comment: "formula", usually.

Comment: does that mean dynamically passing it at run time!?

Comment: Yes, it means it's generated at runtime from an expression.

Answer (score 5):

While the symbol is new, the concept is in SSIS 2008: It simply means that that particular task or component has one or more properties being set using an [SSIS Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137547.aspx) rather than explicitly hard-coded.

From the documentation:

> In SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), a special icon marker displays next
>   to connection managers, variables, and tasks that have expressions set
>   on them. The HasExpressions property is available on all SSIS objects
>   that support expresions, with the exception of variables. The property
>   enables you to easily identy which objects have expressions.

Answer (score 4):

To build on Kyle's answer, right-click the Execute SQL Task and select Properties. In the properties window, find the Expressions and expand the `+`. Under that, you'll see all the properties that are set using Expressions.

[image: Properties]

I love using expressions, they make static packages much more flexible and able to respond to changes. However, the downside to expressions is that you cannot debug them. If you put a breakpoint on the Execute SQL Task, you can't see what an expression evaluates to.

In my trivial example, nothing it going on so it's easy to parse what the expression evaluates to. However, if I had something like this...

```
"SELECT * FROM " @[User::TableName] + " AS X WHERE X.DayOfWeek ='" + (DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 1 ? "Sunday" : DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 2 ? "Monday" :
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 3 ? "Tuesday" : DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 4 ? "Wednesday" :
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 5 ? "Thursday" : DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 6 ? "Friday" :
DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()) == 7 ? "Saturday" : "InvalidDay") + "';"
```

good luck with the mental parsing.

I find I am more successful at debugging complex expressions if I do all the work in SSIS variables. In the above example, I'd create a variable called Query of type String. I'd then use the above expression on the variable. I'd then set the SqlStatementSource to be @[User::Query] instead of doing the logic in the Task. The net result is the same except now if things are acting "funny", I can set a breakpoint on the Task and then inspect the value of my Variable because it has been evaluated. It's a subtle difference but a significant one.